# Android fazer autenticação constantemente com servidor externo

Tags: android, autenticação, sincronização

Pessoal gostaria de saber como fazer para o aplicativo que estou desenvolvendo faça autenticação constantemente.

Por exemplo o *watts* se vc não tem acesso a internet e tenta mandar uma mensagem ela fica guardada e o app fica constantemente tentando mandar essa mensagem e quando vc volta a ter acesso a internet ele manda a mensagem pro servidor imediatamente.

No meu caso meu app tera uma versão desktop dessa forma eu vou usar o servidor para sincronizar as informações do usuário entre os dois dispositivos, por exemplo o usuário acessa com seu login o app Android e altera sua imagem de perfil dai o app atualiza essa imagem localmente e depois envia pro servidor e quando o usuário for abrir o app versão desktop ele baixa essa atualização do servidor e vice versa.

Alguém sabe como fazer isso? Estou usando wampserver + php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom com as minhas pesquisas achei um modo que no começo achei um exagero para uma simples tarefa, mas como não achei nem outro modo melhor então vou usar este. vou usar a classe Sync Adapter junto com outras que vi na documentação do Android que pelo que li ela faz essa constante verificação de conexão com o servidor ta ai o link para quem precisar:

http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/training/sync-adapters/index.html

Obrigado pela resposta anterior @Alessandro Barreto.

Answer (score 0):

É tudo uma questão de logica do programador.
Eu faria da seguinte maneira ex: caso das mensagens do whatsapp citadas por você.
Criaria uma coluna na minha tabela chamada **STATUS**, nela eu salvaria as seguintes informações:

**0-mensagem não enviada**

**1-mensagem enviada**

Se (*na hora que o usuário digitou a mensagem,enviou tiver a internet*) **salvar com o status 1**

caso contrario (*salva com o status 0, porque a mensagem não foi enviada*) seguindo.

Toda vez que o usuário abrir a aplicação e estiver com internet ou a app estiver fechada e um BroadcastReceiver detectar a presença de internet, faria um select em todas as mensagens com **status 0** (*ou seja as mensagens que não foram enviadas*) e já que agora vai tá com a internet para enviar a mensagem (seguindo a regra de negocio 'so envia mensagem se estiver conexão com a internet') atualizaria as mensagem para **status 1** (*que simboliza as mensagens enviadas com sucesso*)

Comment: a lógica de quando enviar eu sei o problema é fazer o app ficar constantemente verificando a conexão com o servidor e eu acho que vc não sabe mas o watts não verifica a conexão com a internet e sim com o servidor, ou seja mesmo com a conexão com a internet se o servidor não estiver disponível ele não manda.